# Text messaging on the iPhone - accessible from the SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, mms

Is there an API in the iOS SDK that deals with text messaging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MessageUI.framework** is what you are looking for.

You can use [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to show system composer for sms.

*The MFMessageComposeViewController class presents a standard system interface for composing SMS text messages. You use this class to configure the initial recipients and body of the message and to configure a delegate to respond to the final result.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html

However, as stated in the iOS documentation:

> Important: If an iOS-based device is
>   not configured to send a given type of
>   message, you should avoid displaying
>   the corresponding composition
>   interface. The view controllers in
>   this framework provide methods for
>   determining if support is available
>   for a given message type.

Answer (score 1):

MessageUI.framework will work, and give you SMS and Email message capabilities

**BUT**

Note that this only works in iOS 4.0. Which means it will not work (currently) on the iPad.

Comment: Note: SMS will probably _never_ work on the iPad, by design. But your point is still valid for the general availability of the framework (i.e. email composure) on iPad devices.

Answer (score 0):

MessageUI.framework will give you ability to compose and send SMS and Emails from iphone, but as per my knowledge there is no way to access SMS or Email from you native app to your app.